# How to get the type of a value as string?

Tags: nim-lang

I would like to know if it is possible to get the type (int32 / float64 / string) from a value in Nim at runtime?

I thought this would be possible with the "typeinfo" library but I can't figure it out!

EDIT: Got an answer and made this real quick:

```
import typetraits

type
    MyObject = object
        a, b: int
        s: string

let obj = MyObject(a: 3, b: 4, s: "abc")

proc dump_var[T: object](x: T) =
    echo x.type.name, " ("
    for n, v in fieldPairs(x):
        echo("    ", n, ": ", v.type.name, " = ", v)
    echo ")"

dump_var obj
```

Output:

```
MyObject (
    a: int = 3
    b: int = 4
    s: string = abc
)
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Close, it's in the [typetraits](http://nim-lang.org/docs/typetraits.html) module:

```
import typetraits

var x = 12
echo x.type.name
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use stringify operator [`$`](https://nim-lang.org/docs/dollars.html#%24%2Ctypedesc), which has a overloaded signature of

```
proc `$`(t: typedesc): string {...}
```

For example,

```
doAssert $(42.typeof) == "int"
```

Note that [nim manual](https://nim-lang.github.io/Nim/manual.html#special-types-typeof-operator) encourages using `typeof(x)` instead of `type(x)`,

> typeof(x) can for historical reasons also be written as type(x) but type(x) is discouraged.